# Parallax scrolling in application not for wallpaper

Tags: android, background, parallax

Could add `parallax effect` to android `app background` and not for `Live Wallpaper`, I Google it but i found for wallpapers. Please any one can help...

Comment: refer  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013855/android-parallax-effect-and-view-pager

Comment: May be this works but i want change on motion not scroll...?